# GNUPlot smooth freq in covid cases

Tags: linux, gnuplot, frequency

So I have a .tsv file which looks somewhat like this:

| Lab | Sample Code | state | city | date | age | ... | variant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| laby | 12345 | NY | NY | 01/01/2022 | 50 | ... | BA.1 |
| labx | 12346 | CAL | LA | 01/01/2022 | 18 | ... | Delta |

I need to be able to make a histogram which puts on each day the number of times a variant has been sequenced grouping together the days (column 5) and counting the instances of each variable (column 16) [looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXiGm.png) (the line plot is the weekly cases and bar plot is sum of a variable cases in a day).

I have tried a lot of different plot commands and structures and none of them have worked, right now what I am trying is:

`plot ["01/01/2022":] "data_25042022.tsv" using 16:xticlabel(5) axes x1y1 title "var" smooth frequency` without setting the time format like trying just to copy
which gets me a `line 0: x range is invalid`

`plot "data_25042022.tsv" using 16:xticlabel(5) axes x1y1 title "var" smooth frequency` with the time format set that returns `line 0: Need full using spec for x time data`

Comment: Problem solved, question answered? Any feedback would be polite and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With your code you are trying to take the variants (column 16) as x for the `smooth freq` option instead of the date (column 5).

You need to know two things:

- date/time is internally handled as seconds passed from Jan, 1st 1970 00:00:00 (check `help strptime`)
- smooth freq should take the seconds from the date as x (i.e. as first input) and in your case either "1" if your variant is the one in consideration or "0" otherwise, i.e. the output of the function `myVarCheck()` is either `0` or `1`. Check `help smooth frequency`.

The following example is minimized to just two columns of interest: date and variant, but can easily be adapted to your data. Skip the random data generation section and replace `$Data` with your filename and the corresponding column numbers.

**Script:**

```
### histogram with string check
reset session

myVars            = "Alpha Beta Gamma Delta"
myDateFmt         = "%m/%d/%Y"
myDate(col)       = strptime(myDateFmt,strcol(col))
myVarCheck(col,v) = strcol(col) eq v

# create some "random" test data
set print $Data
    Gauss(x,x0,A,FWHM) = A * exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*(FWHM/(2*sqrt(2*log(2))))**2))
    p1(t) = Gauss(t,strptime(myDateFmt,"02/14/2022"),10,3600*24*80)  * (1+(rand(0)*0.1-0.05))
    p2(t) = Gauss(t,strptime(myDateFmt,"06/15/2022"),20,3600*24*120) * (1+(rand(0)*0.1-0.05))
    p3(t) = Gauss(t,strptime(myDateFmt,"08/20/2022"),15,3600*24*200) * (1+(rand(0)*0.1-0.05))
    p4(t) = Gauss(t,strptime(myDateFmt,"10/30/2022"),30,3600*24*80)  * (1+(rand(0)*0.1-0.05))
    do for [i=0:364] {
        t = strptime(myDateFmt,"01/01/2022") + 3600*24*i
        do for [i=1:int(p1(t))] { print sprintf("%s %s", strftime(myDateFmt,t), word(myVars,1)) }
        do for [i=1:int(p2(t))] { print sprintf("%s %s", strftime(myDateFmt,t), word(myVars,2)) }
        do for [i=1:int(p3(t))] { print sprintf("%s %s", strftime(myDateFmt,t), word(myVars,3)) }
        do for [i=1:int(p4(t))] { print sprintf("%s %s", strftime(myDateFmt,t), word(myVars,4)) }
    }
set print

set format x "%b" timedate
set key out
set grid x,y

plot for [myVar in myVars] $Data u (myDate(1)):(myVarCheck(2,myVar)) smooth freq w l ti myVar
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]